# how to get user facebook email id (that is used for login)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know this is not a right question for SO format. I am asking as many experts are here.

My friend have a fake account (this fake account is not in my friend list). I want to know the email id with which he logged in for the fake account.

I tried http://graph.facebook.com/username.

Here username is the userid or the username (that FB creates).

Is there any way where I can get the user email id with which the user gets logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that revealing a person's email without consent would be a violation of that person's privacy, this is not possible.

The only way to get access to this data would be to have the user grant the `email` permission to your app, at which point you could use `/me?fields=email`.

Comment: you meant there is no way?

Comment: after I add myself, is there way I can come to know then? I think Contact Info will give me details of what I am looking for... right?

Comment: Correct, there is no way to get this information - it would violate the persons privacy if you could.

Comment: hmmm, that's what I was thinking... Someone said we can find the info... hence I was searching how can...